# Running Python Script in Veins

Tags: python, omnet++, veins, sumo

I already have SUMO, OMNET++ and Veins running on my machine, but I am new to Veins. I would like to run Python scripts using Veins framework.

Let us say in the Python script we are given two objects `object_A` and `object_B` that contain data about the corresponding cars `car_A` and `car_B`. I would like to enable some exchange of information between the `object_A` and `object_B` based on the scenario happening in Veins. Could somebody explain to me, how can I accomplish my goal or point me to the corresponding literature?

I found [this repository](https://github.com/veins/veins_python) where Python and Veins are combined, but I cannot make sense of it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Veins_Python (as of Dec 2021) is no more than a simple illustration of how to call python code from Veins and vice versa. The project can serve as inspiration for how to write such code yourself - it is not in a state where you can just download and use it without adapting it to your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

[How to use pybind11 in omnet++ projects like veins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71013592/7215379)

You can try using pybind11 as done in the above link if you are running veins in Linux environment.